# How to prepare string in SAS to insert into teradata

Tags: sql, string, escaping, quotes, sas

Does anyone know how to prepare a string in SAS for insert into external database(teradata for ex.)
I mean if there is a function like php's addslashes or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There are a few ways you could do this, though. The most flexible would probably be to use the Perl Regular Expression functionality built into SAS such as `CALL PRXCHANGE`. Documentation is [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002295959.htm).